# ui-select on-highlight event not working

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

From the documentation:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices#events

It says:
on-highlight event occurs when an item was hovered on. Example: `on-highlight="showPreview(myValue)"`.

I tried this, but the event is triggered upon clicking the down arrow to open the dropdown, and is triggered `x` times, where `x` is the number of choices on the list.

The weirder thing is that the behavior varies from one version of ui-select to the next.
In version 0.11.2 it is working but triggering extra events and double events, and in 0.13.1 it just triggers the extra events as I explained above.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6vBETab35YTvT0j39wkO?p=preview

Your help is appreciated.